# How to detect that the close button of QWidget is pressed?

Tags: c++, qt

I create a new [QWidget](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html) object and I want to know when the close button is pressed.

I have tried the following code:

```
pWindow = new QWidget();
connect(pWindow , SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(processCloseButtonWindowsClicked()));
```

but it give an error:

> no signal triggered of pWindow

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## Cause

`QWidget` does not have a `triggered` signal.

## Solution

I would suggest you to:

1. Subclass `QWidget` and reimplement [`QWidget::closeEvent`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#closeEvent)
2. Check [`QEvent::spontaneous`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qevent.html#spontaneous) to differentiate between a click of the close button and the call to [`QWidget::close`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#close)
3. According to your app's logic either call `QWidget::closeEvent(event);` to close the widget, or [`QEvent::ignore`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qevent.html#ignore) to leave it open

## Example

I have prepared an example for you of how to implement the proposed solution:

```
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QCloseEvent>
#include <QPushButton>

class FooWidget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit FooWidget(QWidget *parent = nullptr) :
        QWidget(parent) {
        auto *button = new QPushButton(tr("Close"), this);
        connect(button, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &FooWidget::close);
        resize(300, 200);
        setWindowTitle("Foo");
    }

protected:
    void closeEvent(QCloseEvent *event) override {

        if (event->spontaneous()) {
            qDebug("The close button was clicked");
            // do event->ignore();
            // or QWidget::closeEvent(event);
        } else {
            QWidget::closeEvent(event);
        }
    }
};

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
    FooWidget *pWindow;
public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr) :
        QMainWindow(parent),
        pWindow(new FooWidget()) {
        pWindow->show();
    }
};
```

Comment: when `close()` is called, `closeEvent()` is also called, as differences between the clicked of the button and the call to `close()`?

Comment: @eyllanesc, do you mean how to differentiate between a call to close and clicking the close button?

Comment: Yes, because the OP wants to detect when the button is clicked: *How to detect that the **close button** of QWidget is pressed?*

Comment: @eyllanesc, I understand now. You are right and I am digging already in the code to find a way to differentiate between the two.

Comment: thanks @scopchanov and @ eyllanesc, i think detect close button of QWidget to override closeEvent()

Answer (score 1):

Before, check if Qt has a class for what you want to do. Maybe you want to use QDialog instead of QWidget for what you want to achieve.

The following code: suppose you want to delete the widget when the X is clicked and you just want to know when to do something.
Try connecting the signal from the base class QObject of your widget when it is Destroyed:

-Your Widget

-attribute setted to destroy your widget after X(closebotton is clicked) or the close() handler is triggered

-connect the destroyed() signal to whatever slot you want to do something before it is destroyed

```
pWindow = new QWidget();
pWindow->setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose,true);
connect(pWindow , SIGNAL(destroyed()), this,SLOT(processCloseButtonWindowsClicked()));
```

for more info:

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#close

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#destroyed

Answer (score -1):

void QWidget::closeEvent(QCloseEvent *event) will be the possible way I would go with.

You can read the documentation [here.](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#closeEvent)