# How to detect when a QWebEngineView widget is opened/closed?

Tags: c++, windows, qt, qtwebengine

I'm adding the discord widget from [widgetbot](https://widgebot) to a grid layout in a way it can expand above other widgets, the problem is, even when the widget is 'closed' the `QWebEngineView` widget occupies the entire area blocking things below it to be clicked:

[image]

I thought of setting a maximum size to the widget when it is opened and another when it's closed so it doesn't overlay other widgets when it's not 'opened'.

I tried installing an `event filter` but it didn't throw any event when the widget is opened/closed, would like to ask what other way I could detect it?

---

```
#include "discordwidget.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    ui.setupUi(this);

    auto wdgt = new DiscordWidget(this);
}
```

---

```
//discordwidget.h
#include <QtWebEngineWidgets>

class DiscordWidget : public QWebEngineView 
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:

    DiscordWidget(QWidget* parent = 0) : QWebEngineView(parent)
    {    
        this->page()->setBackgroundColor(Qt::transparent);   
        
        // Tutorial: https://docs.widgetbot.io/embed/crate/tutorial/#getting-started
        this->page()->setHtml(R"(    
            <script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@widgetbot/crate@3' async defer>
            new Crate({
                server: '', // Replace with your discord server
                channel: '' // ... channel
            })
            </script>    
        )");

        this->installEventFilter(this);
        this->page()->installEventFilter(this);    
    } 

    bool eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *e)
    {
        qDebug() << e->type();

        if( e->type() == QEvent::ChildAdded )
        {
            QChildEvent *ce = static_cast<QChildEvent*>(e);
            ce->child()->installEventFilter(this);
        }
        return false;
    }    
};
```

Comment: Maybe use width and height from here https://docs.widgetbot.io/embed/react-embed/props/#props

Comment: @ניר it would result in the same thing, I need to know when the widget is opened/closed to set the widget width according.

Comment: Maybe wrap the button with transparent QWidget and propogate the mouse events?

Comment: Or hook to some javascript event https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61764733/capture-a-javascript-event-in-qtwebengine

Comment: @ניר i couldn't get this working, i didnt get any message, what about you?

Answer (score 0):

I stuck with the problem myself and, I guess, there are no beautiful solutions.

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53165314/19827315) answer: `QWebEngineView`, like `QWidget` itself, does not have any signals on closing. So, you may want to implement it yourself:

```
class YourWindow : public QWebEngineView
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit YourWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr) : QWebEngineView{parent} { }
protected:
    void closeEvent(QCloseEvent *event) override {
        QWebEngineView::closeEvent(event);
        emit this->YourWindowClosed();
}
signals:
    void YourWindowClosed();
};
```

Further, you can `connect` your signal to any slot that fits your purpose:

```
YourWindow* View = new YourWindow();
QObject* Foo = new QObject();
connect(View, SIGNAL(LoginWindowClosed()), Foo, SLOT(AnySlotYouNeed()));
```

Hope that helps.